# How can I show the days of last week in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need a script that show the days of the last week, until today. 
But when it's early in the month, like on day 4, my code has this problem. 
I'm using getDate(). Is there a function that can help me?

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHpT4.png)

Comment: Edit your question to include your code. Per the posting guidelines: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getDay` method which gives the day of the week (1-monday, 3-wednesday). From this value you can put a decreasing loop till 1-monday or 0-sunday to show previous day of week.

```
var weekdays = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
var d = new Date();
var currDay = d.getDay();
var currDate = d.getDate();
var str = "";
for(var count=currDay; count>=0 && currDate >= 1; count--, currDate--){
    str += currDate +" "+weekdays[count] + ", ";
}
console.log(str);
```

Today's output: `5 Fri, 4 Thu, 3 Wed, 2 Tue, 1 Mon`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getDate()`, but don't put it in a variable that you then just decrement with the risk of going to 0 and below.

Instead use `setDate()` (potentially in combination with `getDate()`) to decrement your date object day by day, and then read out the date in the format you want:

```js
var dt = new Date();
headers = ['Hoje'];
for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
    headers.push(dt.toLocaleDateString('pt-PT').substr(0,5));
}
console.log(headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

To go back a week from today, regardless of where in the month you are (even within seven days from the beginning of the month), just .setDate() to a value that is seven (days) less than what .getDate() gives:

```
var d = new Date()
d.toDateString()
"Thu May 04 2017"

// go back a week
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
1493321406767

// prove that it worked
d.toDateString()
"Thu Apr 27 2017"
```